# How to get user email using JSF and WebSphere?

Tags: java, jsf, session, authorization

I have configured my test environment using WebSphere 8.5.5.5 and Active Directory for authorization.

I would like to get access to more user data. 
For now I have access only to user "id" using java bean with:

```
String userName = facesContext.getExternalContext().getRemoteUser();
```

That's okay, but I would like to get more information, for example email adress, but I can't find any other methods.

Is there a way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

That ExternalContext in this case is only the authentication context, and only contains things like the auth token and principal.

To get more information from Active Directory you need to query as an LDAP source.

Here's a [big blog post](http://myjeeva.com/querying-active-directory-using-java.html) about how to do that.